# Showing Plugin in post page wordpress theme development

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, codex, loginradius

I am learning how to develop wordpress theme. I want to share posts. I am using social sharing by loginradius plugin. Plugin url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/

I enabled this plugin. but social sharing widget is not showing. I changed setting of the plugin to show the widget in the bottom of the post. But it is not working. I think there is some problem in my theme. Is there any code to show that plugin in the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a sharing widget three ways:

1. Using the settings in the loginradius admin to set location on pages, posts, homepage etc.
2. Use a sharing shortcode within a post `[LoginRadius_Share]`
3. Use a sharing shortcode in your theme code `<?php do_shortcode('[LoginRadius_Share]'); ?>`

Best way to figure out if it is your theme or placement is place the `<?php do_shortcode('[LoginRadius_Share]'); ?>` in a page like single.php outside of the loop and see if it shows on a single post. The sharing widget should show as long as you're using one of these three methods and you have Enable horizontal sharing on.

Answer (score 0):

A couple people were having an issue of no sharing widget showing if there was no API Key entered. If you do not have an API Key add 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 in the API Key field to see if that helps